# html encode <textarea> value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the latest updated typed in value of a textarea and html encode the value.

To get the value I use:

```
$('textarea').val(); // this works cross browser
```

But if the value was `"sdfgsdgdsgsdg <br/>"`     how do I HTML encode it?

It breaks when I `stringify()` it

```
var e = { "d" : $('textarea').val()};
var s = JSON.stringify(e); //it breaks here
```

Comment: `var s = {"a":"sdfgsdgdsgsdg <br/>"};` does not error (nor is it JSON,  it is JavaScript)

Comment: you may find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding

Comment: You HTML encode strings to make them HTML friendly, not JSON friendly.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
var string = $('textarea').val();
var encoded = $('<div/>').text(string).html();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/qhsUL/)

Comment: looks great thanks... why do you have to put in the "<div/>"?

Comment: @Hello-World We've to use some element to set it's text to escape the `string`. This case the element's the `div`.

Comment: so one fore question   what the difference between your solution and escape() ? thanks.

Comment: @Hello-World Escape encode special characters(with some exceptions), this way you'll only encode the necessary to html entities.

Answer (score 0):

> it break here

That isn't a very helpful description of the error, but I'm guessing you mean *I get an empty object*.

Spell `textarea` correctly (it doesn't have an `e` in the middle), so that you assign the value of the textarea instead of `undefined` (which is what you get when you call `val()` on an empty jQuery object).

This has nothing to do with HTML encoding. HTML isn't involved in this process at all. You take user input from a DOM, and then put it into JSON. JSON.stringify takes care of all your encoding needs.

Comment: @Hello-World — Why do you want to? HTML encoding is entirely irrelevant for the problem you describe.